# Group by DF and then Filter using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This might be relatively easy in `dplyr`.  Sample question uses the `Lahman` package data.

What player managed both the `NYA` and `NYN` under `teamID`?

```
# get master player table
players <- Lahman::People

# get manager table
managers <- Lahman::Managers

# merge players to managers
manager_tbl <- 
  managers %>% 
  left_join(players)
```

I want to get the results for the players under `playerID` that have a row for both `NYA` and `NYN` under `teamID`.

How would I go about doing this?  I'm guessing that I would need to group at `playerID`.  `berrayo01` is one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'playerID', `filter` all groups having both 'NYA' and 'NYN' `%in%` 'teamID'

```
library(dplyr)
manager_tbl %>%
        group_by(playerID) %>%
         filter(all(c("NYA", "NYN") %in% teamID))
# A tibble: 69 x 35
# Groups:   playerID [4]
#   playerID yearID teamID lgID  inseason     G     W     L  rank plyrMgr birthYear birthMonth birthDay birthCountry birthState birthCity deathYear deathMonth deathDay deathCountry deathState
#   <chr>     <int> <fct>  <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>       <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>         <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>        <chr>     
# 1 stengca…   1934 BRO    NL           1   153    71    81     6 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 2 stengca…   1935 BRO    NL           1   154    70    83     5 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 3 stengca…   1936 BRO    NL           1   156    67    87     7 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 4 stengca…   1938 BSN    NL           1   153    77    75     5 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 5 stengca…   1939 BSN    NL           1   152    63    88     7 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 6 stengca…   1940 BSN    NL           1   152    65    87     7 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 7 stengca…   1941 BSN    NL           1   156    62    92     7 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 8 stengca…   1942 BSN    NL           1   150    59    89     7 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# 9 stengca…   1943 BSN    NL           2   107    47    60     6 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
#10 stengca…   1949 NYA    AL           1   155    97    57     1 N            1890          7       30 USA          MO         Kansas C…      1975          9       29 USA          CA        
# … with 59 more rows, and 14 more variables: deathCity <chr>, nameFirst <chr>, nameLast <chr>, nameGiven <chr>, weight <int>, height <int>, bats <fct>, throws <fct>, debut <chr>,
#   finalGame <chr>, retroID <chr>, bbrefID <chr>, deathDate <date>, birthDate <date>
```

Comment: How would I print the results showing just one row per playerID that meets the criteria?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz  You meant to show only the rows where `NYA` and 'NYN`, in that case, after the `filter` step, do `%>% filter(teamID %in% c("NYA", "NYN"))`